# How to have stable connectivity from Alamofire on iOS background

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, watchkit

From my Watch, I send commands to my iOS app. It's not clear why but if the app is in the background I can see some errors:

`Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-997 "Lost connection to background transfer service"`

`Can't end BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 383 (0x17f), or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.`

I've already tried to change my configuration to background, have a correct identifier for my config.
Static or Lazy implementation of my SessionManager.
Count for deinit on the process.

Network Session manager

```swift
static var sessionManager: SessionManager = {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: UUID().uuidString + ".WatchOS_Background")
        configuration.httpShouldSetCookies = false
        configuration.httpMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 4
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 50
        configuration.networkServiceType = .background
        configuration.isDiscretionary = false
        configuration.shouldUseExtendedBackgroundIdleMode = true
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            configuration.allowsExpensiveNetworkAccess = true
            configuration.allowsConstrainedNetworkAccess = true
        }

        let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
        sessionManager.delegate.sessionDidBecomeInvalidWithError = { _, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        sessionManager.delegate.taskDidComplete = { _, task, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        return sessionManager
    }()
```

Request example

```swift
func getListFromServer(completion: @escaping (ServiceResponse<[Model1]>) -> Void) {
        let header: HTTPHeaders = ["User-Agent": UserAgentHelper.fullUserAgentString]
        request("/api/1/XXXX", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: nil, headers: header).responseData { [weak self] response in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
            completion(strongSelf.completionResponse(response))
        }
    }
```

Request method

```swift
@discardableResult private func request(
        _ path: String,
        method: HTTPMethod,
        parameters: Parameters? = nil,
        encoding: ParameterEncoding? = nil,
        headers: HTTPHeaders? = nil)
        -> DataRequest {
            let userEncoding = encoding ?? self.defaultEncoding
            let task = beginBackgroundTask()
            let dataRequest = NetworkService.sessionManager.request("\(API)\(path)",
                method: method,
                parameters: parameters,
                encoding: userEncoding,
                headers: headers)

            dataRequest.validate()

            self.endBackgroundTask(taskID: task)
            return dataRequest
    }
```

Begin and end background task

```swift
func beginBackgroundTask() -> UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier {
      return UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(withName: "Background_API", expirationHandler: {})
}

func endBackgroundTask(taskID: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier) {
      UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(taskID)
}
```

I hope to have a proper implementation from your and a stable request life cycle.

Many thanks for your help and sorry in advance for the lack of technical terms.

Answer (score 1):

Your core problem is that you're not properly handling the expiration of your background tasks. You must end the tasks in their expiration handler explicitly:

```swift
let task = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(withName: "Background_API") {
    UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(task)
}
```

I suggest you read more [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/85066), where an Apple DTS engineer has extensively outlined the requirements and edge cases of the background task handling.

Additionally, Alamofire doesn't really support background sessions. Using a foreground session with background task handling is probably your best bet. Once the Alamofire `SessionManager` is deinitialized, any requests it has started will be cancelled, even for background sessions.

Finally, calling `validate()` within an Alamofire response handler is invalid. You should be calling it on the request before the response handler is added, as it's validates the response before handlers are called. If you're calling it afterward it won't be able to pass the error it produces to your response handler.